# Make a letter at given index in a string to uppercase

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a letter in a particular index in a string to uppercase.

I have a string:

`let str = "Dwightschrute";`

I could do:

```
let str = "Dwightschrute";

let a = str.slice(0, 6);
console.log(a); //Dwight

let b = (str.slice(6, 7)).toUpperCase();
console.log(b); // S

let c = str.slice(7);

console.log(c);

console.log(a+b+c); //DwightSchrute
```

Or

```
let str = "Dwightschrute";

str = [...str];

str[6] = str[6].toUpperCase();

console.log(str.join('')); //DwightSchrute
```

Is there a better way to do this? I think I am doing a lot of unnecessary stuff to achieve this

Comment: first version is good to go, don't think there are other simple way possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd prefer the first version, only without the intermediate variables, and you can use bracket notation instead of a `.slice` function call to extract just one character, it looks pretty clean:

```js
const str = "Dwightschrute";
const result = str.slice(0, 6) + str[6].toUpperCase() + str.slice(7);
console.log(result); //DwightSchrute
```

Another method would be to use a regular expression which matches one character after 6 characters, then uses a replacer function to call `toUpperCase` on that character, though whether this looks like an improvement or not is up to you:

```js
const str = "Dwightschrute";
const result = str.replace(/(?<=.{6})./, char => char.toUpperCase());
console.log(result); //DwightSchrute
```

Or, without lookbehind:

```js
const str = "Dwightschrute";
const result = str.replace(/(.{6})(.)/, (_, initial, char) => initial + char.toUpperCase());
console.log(result); //DwightSchrute
```